# What is an efficient concise way to check if values in column of DataTable are contained in SQL query results?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am converting data from a CSV file into a database. I put the data from the CSV file into a `DataTable` and am trying to validate the data.

One thing I want to check is that all of the values in a certain column of the `DataTable` (let's call it `PersonID`) are found in the columns of a table in the database I'm converting to (let's call that `PeopleID`).

So, I want to check if all of the values of `PersonID` are listed in the `PeopleId` table.

I have the results of the `DataTable` as follows:

```
var listOfPersonIdsInData = arguments.DataTable.Select("PersonId");
```

And I query the database to get the values of the `PeopleId` column:

```
var listOfPeopleIdsInDatabase = checkQuery.Execute<DataColumn>(@"SELECT DISTINCT PeopleId FROM People");`
```

What would be the best way to go about checking this in C#? I realize it's a somewhat basic question but the way I'm thinking of doing it is using two arrays. Read in the results of each into an array, then cycle through each value of array 1 to check if it's in array 2.

I feel like I'm re-inventing the wheel. I would really like to know a better way if there is one. If anyone could provide any advice I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL 2008 I would recommend that you just pass the DataTable as parameter as a [Table-Valued](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) Parameter to a stored procedure or a Parameterized query and then use an Anti Join or Not In or Not Exists to determine if there are any rows in the DataTable that aren't in the SQL Table.

e.g.

Create the type

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.PersonTable AS TABLE
    ( PersonId int )
```

Then the proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ValidateDataTable 
(@CheckTable dbo.PersonTable READONLY) as 

 BEGIN

     SELECT c.PersonID 
      FROM  
           @CheckTable  c
      WHERE
             c.Person NOT IN (SELECT PersonID from dbo.People)

 END
```

C# Code
SP Call

```
  SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("usp_ValidateDataTable" , cnn);
  SqlParameter tvpParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckTable", listOfPersonIdsInData );
  tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
  tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.PersonTable";
  SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExcuteReader();
```

C# Code
Parameterized Query Call

```
 string query = @" SELECT c.PersonID 
                   FROM  @CheckTable  c
                   WHERE c.Person NOT IN (SELECT PersonID from dbo.People)";

  SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(query  , cnn);
  SqlParameter tvpParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckTable", listOfPersonIdsInData );
  tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
  tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.PersonTable";
  SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExcuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had to migrate much information and so far I think the best is:

1. Create a flat table with the information from the CSV and load all the data there
2. Create in the same SQL methods to extract standardized information
3. Construct a method in the same SQL crossing normalized information with the raw data

is really fast especially when the number of records is quite large (greater than 1M), plus you avoid the problem of optimizing your RAM management script/program. also load CSV to MySQL data is really easy check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

**a tip**: parameterized method for import and verify with an offset and limit value

Comment: This is a tried and true approach and works on every Client/Backend combo but managing the staging tables is a drag (e.g. deleting the rows when you're done). Its also does take some thought to deal with concurrent processing of CSV's but that's rarely a true use case.